# Can one make an excel-vba file using an odbc link portable?

Tags: excel, odbc, portability, vba

The same problem happens every time: We build a Excel/VBA tool using an ODBC link but for other people to use it first we need to call IT and have the ODBC link set up in the user machine.

What would be the smart way to skip this call to IT?

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface by saying that I don't know if this will work as I don't have a way to test.

After setting up an ODBC link, you should be able to Export the Connection File by

1. Clicking on `Data > Connections` in the ribbon.
2. Select your connection and click the `Properties` button
3. On the `Definition` tab, click `Export Connection File...`

Then use the connection file instead of the connection string

1. On same `Definition` tab click `Browse...`
2. Select your connection file
3. Click `Always use connection file`

I would consider saving the connection file in a shared folder, that way the link won't change between users, but I suppose that you could save it locally as well.

Hopefully that gets you started.